# Importing DB with drush from sql dump not working

Tags: drush

I made a dump of my live's DB from cPanel and I'm now trying to import it into my dev environment using drush sql:cli < [dbdumpfile]. It's not showing any errors but no data is getting into the destination DB. It's basically failing silently.
Drupal 8.8.5, php 7.3.1, drush 8.3.0 all that running on Docker 2.1.0.3 (Mac OS).

This is something I've done many times before so I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Bit old your Drush. We're on version 10 now. Maybe try to update Drush first. Then also try the debug flag to the command. All other commands running normally? Did you try a different dump as well? What file format? Is your site built with Composer? Drush listed as local dependency? Please update your question for clarification. Many thanks

Comment: Check the file size - is it empty ? Also you can pass the -debug or - verbose to get more info

Comment: @leymannx Just updated drush to v9. Yes, the other drush commands are working and I've tried a different dump file as well. The file is in sql format and I'm managing the site with composer.

Comment: @Salah-1 The file is not empty.

Comment: Can you post  how you invoking drush and path ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
drush -vd sqlc < path-to-dump.sql
```

Or

```
   drush -vd sql-cli < path-to-dump.sql
```

Note:  now days drush gets installed via compose (not by default) and is located in /vendor folder (/vendor/drush/drush/drush status

Comment: I learned my `which drush` located in `~/bin/drush/drush` kills color coding which `vendor/bin/drush` has. (they as the same version)